# what is zero of order 1 at infinity of a function?

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

In this given function,$$f(x)=\frac{(x-1)^2}{(x+2)^3}$$has a zero of order 2 at $x=1$ and has a pole of order 3 at $x=−2$
and a zero of order 1 at infinity.

I understand that function f will be zero if $x = 1$.
I also understand that function f will be 'infinity' if $x = -2$. Because of the denominator will become zero.
However, I could not understand this line 'function $f$ has a zero of order 1 at infinity'. Could you please explain this. Thank you.

Comment: It means $f(\frac 1 x)$ has  a zero of order $1$ at $0$

Comment: Does it mean replace the x in the function f, with 1/x ? $f(1/x)=\frac{ {(1/x-1)^2} }{ (1/x+2)^3 }$

Comment: Yes, that is what it means.

Comment: Try expanding and dividing the numerator and denominator. That’ll help.

Comment: Please tag your question properly.

Comment: Another explanation: $f(z)$ tends to $0$ at infinity and $zf(z)$ has a nonzero limit at infinity.

Comment: @MathAndPhysics, why expand it? Just multiply numerator and denominator by $x^3$.

Comment: ok i will do it.